# After Installation of Lubuntu 22.04 no graphical output anymore

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

Mainboard N68-GS3 UCC, 8GB Ram, External Grafic card
Installation via DVD Image.

During installation, I got the message "start snap daemon failed" and the system hangs up.

After all, I did use the "try Lubuntu feature", got the system 22.04 with DVD image, checked some applications like Firefox, all OK.

From the Desktop I did install Lubuntu 22.04.
Got the "all done" by the installation procedure and will be prompted by Lubuntu to restart the system.
After restart, again I got the message "start snap daemon failed"...

So hard Reset and restart with the "recovery mode". By recovery mode the system did boot correctly. I did try some applications (Libre-Office, Firefox), all OK.
Restart the system (warm reboot) via Lubuntu 22.04, no failure message during boot.
Shut down system, the system did switched off, all OK.
Boot the system again, all works fine.

Next day, I did start the system with the following result :

No graphical output,

DVD drive: It is not possible to open the drive.

Mainboard On/Off switch does not work anymore.

Has someone an idea what is "going on" ?

Comment: Did you remove your installation media after the install (*when you were prompted to restart*?)  The *no failure* message you mention on restart sounds like you're still booting your installation media (*and it's performing installation media checks*)...   The *snap daemon* issue has been discussed here - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/bug-failed-snap-daemon-in-lubuntu-22-04-lts-no-firefox-help-please/3246 so you're not the first to experience that...

Comment: I were not prompted to remove the installation media, but I did. But it is also not possible anymore to boot into BIOS. It seems that the bios functions are completely disabled (no Keyboard response a.s.o.).

Comment: If your hardware power switch no longer powers-on the machine, that's a hardware fault. Ubuntu has no way to change the fundamental behavior the hardware switch or BIOS. Ubuntu can only *react* to those inputs.

Comment: The following I did to get again a running system :

    Power cable removed, CMOS-Battery removed, HDD removed.

    Power cable connected, switch On PC, wait for 1 min.

    Power cable removed, CMOS-Battery plugged in, Power cable connected

Result : Reset of Bios. After all I had access to the keyboard, DVD-Drive a.s.o.

    Now I have also access to Bios, set to "boot from DVD". Again switched of the PC, plugged in the HDD, switched On and installed Lubuntu 20.04. Now I have a running system.

Comment: Your issue seems to be more hardware related than software... yes Lubuntu 22.04 LTS has a newer *kernel stack* than Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (*which you've not been specific about; thus I can't know which kernel stack you're using there, it could be 5.4, or 5.13 - or something in between if not fully-upgraded*) but that won't impact the machine turning on or boot process (which your boxes *firmware* controls).

Comment: Please read above, Result : Reset of Bios. After installation of 20.04 I did confirm fully upgrade the SW, so it is 5.13. I must say, it is not a good idea by Ubuntu to write anything to Bios. It is the task of the user, no one else shall do it.

Comment: Next try, to get 22.04 : 1. done all of s.https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/D/upgrading.html until : "No new release found", therefore edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades => Prompt=lts to Prompt=normal and update to "normal". 2. Upgrade Kernel, s.https://nextgentips.com/2021/11/01/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-5-13-to-5-15-on-ubuntu-21-10/ 3. Edit again file release-upgrades to Prompt=lts and upgrading as described "1.". Now I have uname -r => 5.15.0-051500rc7-generic and  lsb_release -a => Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I hope not confuse the automatic SW-Updater, but system works fine.

Comment: Last try : Back to Lubuntu 20.04, installation via DVD, got again the message "failed to start snap daemon". But continuously DVD read action could be recognized. I did wait > 20min and after all the first page of the installation procedure could be seen. The installation takes a very long time, but after all, Lubuntu 22.04 is now installed. Beneath : I did check the image, burned with verification, but with 3 PCs I had allways the "failed to start snap daemon" message.

Comment: Obviously not the last try : Back to Lubuntu 20.04, then fully dist upgrade "normal". After dist upgrade, settings back to LST, again fully dist upgrade, and now I have a 22.04 Ubuntu LTS with the former Lubuntu Desktop. Some problems with DKMS Wlan driver, used another USB-Port and now its stable.